# JPA Inheritence Annotation on Sub Entity Hierarchy

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

Is it possible to use @Inheritence Annotation and different strategy at different hierarchy ?

[image: Inheritence strategy hierarchy]

```
The inheritance strategy and the discriminator column are only specified in the root of an entity class
hierarchy or subhierarchy .
```

But different strategy allowed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing inheritance strategies within a single entity inheritance hierarchy is not a supported JPA configuration. The JPA specification states:

> The combination of inheritance strategies within a single entity inheritance hierarchy is not defined by this specification.

Comment: So final result is no or support with any conflict .

Comment: Correct JPA does not define a behavior. It is possible that an implementor could define a behavior, however making use of that behavior would not be portable.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so, please correct me if I am wrong. You can use `mixed-inheritance` with same hierarchy applying different strategies. Use

```
@SecondaryTable(
name = "SUBTABLE",
pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "SUB_TABLE_ID");
```

before your sub-class definition. Using this, you apply for example `SINGLE_TABLE` strategy and have separated sub-class table.